# Interrupted apt-get starting whenever I do anything with apt-get

Tags: command-line, apt, java, interrupts

Some time ago I followed those instructions, because I wanted Java 8:

[Install Oracle Java 6 / 7 / 8 on Ubuntu 13.10](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/install-oracle-java-6-7-8-on-ubuntu-13-10/)

Installation did not complete successfully.

Now whenever I start `apt-get` with `sudo apt-get <whatever>`, after the `<whatever>` command has executed, apt automatically runs the java installer again which fails every time.

How do I stop the installer from running whenever I run `apt-get`?

I have also noticed that the java installer keeps failing, but fills my disk space a lot. So a hint on where these files are would also be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You stop apt-get corrections with this:

```
apt-get install -f
```

The packages `oracle-java6/7/8-installer` don't install any executable, this one in the config process, download and install java6/7/8 from oracle site in `/var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer` you can see the downloaded files from oracle site in the dir.

Comment: Not working... I get this: http://pastebin.com/9RrcUjgK

Comment: Find the file jdk-8u66-linux-i586.tar.gz, delete it, then try again.

Comment: @Jos that re-downloads the file and runs out of space on my live USB and fails.

Comment: why are you installing Java directly from a live USB ? are you installing Java for your Linux in the USB or for the server/workstation ?